# Undefined local variable or method `translator' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby, local-variables

I've used a gem and tried to create a method (trans) in my code.

```
require 'yandex-translator'

translator = Yandex::Translator.new(api_key)

def trans(text)
  a = translator.translate text, to: "ru"
  return a
end

puts trans("stack")
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
'trans': undefined local variable or method `translator' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Why did I get this error, and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`translator` variable in this code is defined on class level, hence it’s a local variable in `main` context (since the whole code is executed in `main` context.)

You are trying to call it from the *instance* context, where it is obviously not defined. The easiest way to overcome it, would be to define `@translator` as being a class’ instance variable:

```
@translator = Yandex::Translator.new(api_key)

def trans(text)
  @translator.translate text, to: "ru"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in this way you are looking for a local variable `translator` and you have not. Some solutions:

make translator global

```
$translator = Yandex::Translator.new(api_key)
```

or pass translator to trans method

```
def trans(translator, text)
  translator.translate text, to: "ru"
end
```